# How to show comment author email in front end comments list

Tags: comments-template

I'm making a multi-authors blog, but the author role don't have acces to wordpress back end admin panel. How to show the comment author email in front end comment list inside the post?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php comment_author_email(); ?>`.

Use it in comment callback function or you can also hook it to your `comment_text`. It will show the comment author's email inside the comment loop.

**But keep in mind the Wordpress instruction:**
Care should be taken to protect the email address and assure that email harvesters do not capture your commenter’s email address. Most assume that their email address will not appear in raw form on the site. Doing so will enable anyone, including those that people don’t want to get the email address and use it for their own means good and bad.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_author_email/

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's working, but i don't know where to put to show inside the comment, actually only the post author can see the comment list. My theme is blossom-fashion